# Structure with to infinitive or gerund or past participle

Tags: past-tense, gerunds, past-participles, gerund-vs-infinitive

I read a vocabulary book . There is a sentence which makes me confused. " The government had passed a bill outlawing  smoking while driving" . I wonder if why the author use "outlawing" here but not outlawed or outlaw. Can you explain this grammar structure for me. I am very bad at grammar

Comment: "Outlawing" is the present participle of the verb "outlaw".  The clause "outlawing smoking while driving" modifies "bill". "Smoking" is gerund and the direct object of "outlawing".

Comment: They could as easily have written, “The government had passed a bill that outlawed smoking while driving.” or one that said, “The government had passed a bill to outlaw smoking while driving.” or one that says, “The government had passed a bill that outlaws smoking while driving.” but they chose to use “outlawing” maybe they thought it sounded better that way.

Comment: I still find it really hard to understand why they use" outlawing " why ????

Answer (score 1):

The sentence "*The government had passed a bill outlawing smoking while driving*" contains an example of a *reduced relative clause* or *non-finite relative clause*. It is reduced from:

> The government had passed a bill *that outlaws* smoking while driving.

and contains the *non-finite* verb *outlawing* (*present participle*).

This is a common English sentence pattern. Here are some more authentic  examples:

> I lost my phone *containing* private information ... .  (*that contains*)
>
> The camera followed the car *driving* around for a little bit. (*that was
>    driving*)
>
> Nirenberg is currently collaborating on a book *exploring* the relative
>   claims of different forms of knowledge. (*that explores*)

*Reduced* or *non-finite* relative clauses (i.e. clauses post-modifying noun phrases) can also be formed with the *past participle*:

> Gundry has denied the fact *stated* in the report. (*that was stated*)
>
> We are actors in a play written by others (*that was written*)

There's a good, brief explanation of reduced relative clauses on [TESOL-direct](https://www.tesol-direct.com/tesol-resources/english-grammar-guide/relative-clauses/).